# win32_NTlogEvent query InsertionStrings property

Tags: powershell, vbscript, event-viewer

I would like to accomplish something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM win32_NTlogEvent WHERE logfile = 'application' AND insertionStrings LIKE '%searchString'
```

I know that insertionString is a string array. so I am unsure of how to access its values with WQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (Powershell):

```
Get-EventLog -Logname "Application" | ?{$_.Message -like "*$STRING*"}
```

This would get all entries in the application log, with the message that matches the $string value.  Is this what you're after?